# How do I extract integers from strings using a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am fetching arbitrary strings from different sources that might contain integers. Here are some examples:

1. `"He owns 3 cars"`
2. `"John has $23 and 50 cents"`
3. `"The range is 1-12 cm"`

I would like to parse them so that the output will be like:

1. `"3"`
2. `"23-50"`
3. `"1-12"`

Answer (score 5):

```
"John has 23$ and 50 cents".scan(/\d+/).join("-") # => "23-50"
"The range is 1-12 cm".scan(/\d+/).join("-") # => "1-12"
"He owns 3 cars".scan(/\d+/).join("-") # => "3"
```

Comment: SERIOUSLY?? thats it? and I was trying to do something stupid like:     `no_re = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})/  
    m = no_re.match(title)` thanks a lot

Comment: @user153138, it's not necessary, nor is it considered good style, to prompt for acceptance. The OP will accept answers that make sense, and if they don't, it's not a big deal. Create answers that are solid and over time you can garner more upvotes than a mere acceptance. Besides, this isn't a race, or a video game, so points don't matter.

Comment: OP has accepted one of seven questions (with answers). The meta.stackoverflow post does not prohibit asking for acceptance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer

Comment: @theTinMan I am new here,so didn't aware of these things.